# When Agile becomes a bit slugish

Tags: agile, scrum

So, we have started trying to work to Agile/scrum in our business to run the software dev team and it's not (in my eyes as a humble dev) working very well. Its getting to the point now where the team (devs/scrum master) are getting very pissed off due to it turning into more of a time and motion exercise than a 'get quality products out the door exercise'.

The main issue is with our backlog, we have a product owner who is also the IT manager. Virtually all of the items on the backlog have really poorly defined stories, nothing has any priority and no one else in the business seems to be having any input into the backlog. It gets filled by the assumption of the IT manager most of the time, and other times based on who in the business shouts the loudest.

We have suggested improvements in the retrospectives but they all seem to fall on deaf ears. As a team, has anyone encountered this before, I'd be interested to hear how they tackled the problem. As far as I'm concerned the business isn't invested so Agile is failing.

Comment: Agile methods require just as much changes in the mindset of the participants as any other methodology. The advantage of agile methods is that the changes are more in line with what developers want in their working environment. But if you just decide to do 'Agile' and don't change anything in how you work then you are going to fail miserably.

Comment: I think the reason for your situation is the backlog; i suppose, working without clear requirements is terrible in all situations.
I agree with @gnat: this post is not really a question.

Comment: Yes, there may be problems, but you could probably do with tightening this question up a little as it reads like a rant and is likely to be closed as a result...

Comment: Funny how this type of question tends to read "Agile/Scrum criticism" on the headline but if you look closely at the contents it all boils down to "someone just didn't do their job" :)

Comment: I can relate to that. And old boss of mine tried to implement scrum on our work, and he did it so poorly that all the project suffered. I can just send you my condolences, and hope you find a better place to work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i know the question can be considered a bit vague, but i was interested to see what other peoples experiences were

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dislike Scrum. It has been described as the least agile agile methodology ever. I think its the cause of much inefficiency and a lot of friction between management and development.

Understand that all published agile methodologies are starting points for your own modification. Scrap the bits that do not work for your environment, add bits that you think would help. Never, ever follow the methodology as if it were holy scripture. It isn't. Often they are just practices that worked for some team and are now published in case they help you. Unfortunately a whole industry has grown around doing agile this way, and they like to tell you to follow the rules - that way you need to buy consultant time to find out how to do it "right". Good for the training company, bad for you.

So you have issues with the scrum way that are not going to be fixed unless you get the IT manager and business team on board. They have to understand and get with the programme for what you're doing to work. But, they are the programme and so it's you who has to change to accommodate them.

You can change scrum to suit, but I think that's a huge task, so change agile method. One of the ones that is very popular and much more in keeping with how old IT managers expect work to progress is [Kanban](https://www.atlassian.com/agile/kanban). Change your dev team to use this, do not be afraid to tweak it, and I think you will suddenly find Agile being a big success across the whole extended team.

Comment: Whilst I agree with a lot of this the nub of the problem is that the stories are poorly defined. Whichever way you spin it, methodology X will not help a bean until the nettle is grasped.

Comment: @RobbieDee true, if you don't know what you're doing then its difficult to do it. But, Kanban will mitigate this by letting you run a bad story until its considered complete, even if it started life poorly defined. You may spin new stories to complete it during its progress, or it may get refined. Scrum requires good stories in order to define them into sprint timeboxes. So, the OP can manage the existing process with Kanban in a way that he cannot with Scrum. (and Kanban is just generally more awesomer than scrum).

Comment: Kanban has a lot of merits over Scrum, but reading the OP's post, I highlight doubt that Kanban would help here.  If the PO is refusing to define stories, then you're just going to see stories stretch off into infinity and management laying the blame for their own failures on developers.

Comment: @StevenBurnap yup. But at least they'll be able to point to the board and say "story X is still in development so we can't take on any extra work until you tell us what we need to complete that first!". Management starts to get a clue at that point. With sprints, you just repeatedly fail to deliver and then its 'your' fault, with Kanban its management's fault. I think this would be step 1 towards a full solution.

Comment: @gbjbaanb - your opinion of management may be too high. The OP's management has already demonstrated that they either don't WANT to define the features, or have no clue what doing so means. In either case, all that's going to happen if the switch to Kanban is that they'll either just blame the devs for the long implement times, or they'll say 'yea, that's done, now here's the next thing' which will be the original thing again. Without management clue, it's not going to help.

Answer (score 4):

> The main issue is with our backlog, we have a product owner who is also the IT manager.  Virtually all of the items on the backlog have really poorly defined stories, nothing has any priority and no one else in the business seems to be having any input into the backlog.

This can be summarized as "the Product Owner is not doing his job".  This is a management issue, not an issue with the methodology.  It needs to be solved through management.

Unfortunately, if the PO is also the manager, this will be hard, and the methods for dealing with it are not about programming but rather dealing with the workplace.

The way scrum says to handle this is to have retrospectives and adjust the process. But if a key member is ignoring the results of this, there's not much you can do.  A methodology won't work if team members don't follow it.

> As far as I'm concerned the business isn't invested so agile is failing

And there's your problem.  If the business isn't invested, it's not going to work.  Software development methodologies fix software problems, not people problems.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed many times a shop will react to an identified problem in their methodology by changing their methodology.  This is often the most dysfunctional thing to do.

"We keep missing sprint deadlines."  "OK, make the sprint longer."

This even seems to work.  But it really only hides the problem.

The methodology will not make you better.  It will show what's wrong.  Methodologies don't get work done.

You have identified a problem!  That's awesome.  Can you prove it's a problem?  Changing the methodology now will make proving that SOOOOO much harder.

With a provable problem what's needed is leadership.  Identify what caused the backlog to be poorly defined.  Provide feedback to the one who defined it.  Get others involved and build a consensus.  Go up the chain as needed.  If the problem is a person who is not performing a change in methodology isn't going to help.  A reorg is.

Rather than change a methodology I prefer to ask if the way we're implementing the methodology is correct.  I've seen a lot of things called agile for no reason other than agile sounded good.

It there is nothing on the backlog that is workable take responsibility and put something workable in the backlog.  You can even tag it so people can find the workable items.  As people start working on only workable items you'll see the problem resolve.

It really only makes sense to talk about changing methodologies to solve pervasive problems that are not localized.  If you said everyone could put stuff in the backlog and the backlog was crap it would be time for a methodology change.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake management make time and time again is taking the sum of sprint estimates to be the delivery date. In fact, I've seen management set a delivery date *in stone* before the first sprint has completed.

Tools that assist with planning are a means to an end - they shouldn't be a tool to beat the developers with. Estimates are indicators for time-lining to the sprint - nothing more.

If your sprint has fatlogs they should be passed back up the chain of command. It is insanity to be moaned at because sprints aren't completed if you're spending most of your time doing analysis on the tasks.

Tasks *can* have priority but the fact that they're in the sprint should be priority enough unless there are dependent tasks.

I too have been in a position when retrospectives were ignored. The reasoning was that the problems should be raised in the stand ups but in reality it was just an excuse for management to sweep the problems under the carpet as the retrospective was documented and distributed but the stand ups weren't. Alarm bells should be ringing!